# Is there an event for a keyboard initiated save in Ace Editor?

Tags: ace-editor

In Mac and Windows when you press COMMAND + S or CTRL + S it typically used to save a document. Does Ace Editor have a cross platform event for this that I can listen for? If not how would I capture the user keyboard initiated save event?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

add a command like this

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: 'save',
    bindKey: {win: "Ctrl-S", "mac": "Cmd-S"},
    exec: function(editor) {
        console.log("saving", editor.session.getValue())
    }
})
```

Comment: Can we use it for Linux also ?? If yes, then what I have to add in `bindKey: {win: "Ctrl-S", "mac": "Cmd-S"}` ?? And, Thank you for giving us a great solution !! :)

Comment: linux uses the same keybinding as windows, there is no way to specify different keybindings for linux only.

Comment: So your mean I have to use 'lin' for Linux OS ??

Comment: Okay !! Thanks a lot !! 